# How to use Nokogiri to scrape data on a cloud development environment (Cloud9)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, cloud9-ide

I'm currently using Cloud9 as a cloud-based IDE, but unfortunately it seems like running things on Cloud9 adds a layer of complexity that I don't quite understand.

For example, the following code, despite being copied and pasted from a tutorial, will not generate any output in the terminal:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://stats.nba.com/player/#!/203096/stats/"
data = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
puts data
```

This leads to two questions:

1. Do I need to deploy this code via something like Heroku, before it can access URLs on the internet? Or will it only work locally until I do that?
2. Where, exactly, is the output supposed to be when I'm not openly running a Ruby console? I'm simply running the file in bash.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it:

1. Goto C9.io and login
2. Click "Workspace" and choose "Custom Template"
3. `mkdir scrape && cd $_`
4. `touch scrape.rb`
5. Paste your code into scrape.rb
6. Run: `ruby scrape.rb`

There you go, everything should be fine.

Comment: Oh wow, I realized I had saved the file I was trying to run this in as .ru and not .rb! Silly mistake on my part. Thanks for helping me figure this out.

Comment: @yoursweater Great, good luck. Can you thump up for points )))

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using OpenUri to get the webpage, this will work on Heroku or on any machine. But you don't need to use Heroku, as you are already able to scrape nba.com on Cloud9.

You said the code you are using doesn't print to console, but it does for me.

It depends what you want to do with the data you parse using Nokogiri. Do you want to save it to a database or file? Look into writing files instead of using the `puts` command to print to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

This code outputs to the console.

First make sure you installed the Nokogiri gem, and you have full Internet connectivity.

Second start debugging. To debug a program you can use a gem like `byebug` that gives you an interactive debugger at runtime. Otherwise, as your code is short, you can add a bunch of `puts "point x"` to actually see where your program halts or break.

Third pay attention to any error or warning you see on the screen.